# Automatic video stops on changhong Android TV

Tags: android, led, television, smart-tv

I have a Changhong Android based LED TV. When I connect USB to it for playing video or play video through internal memory, it plays for 1 or 2 minutes and then automatically exits the video I think it happens due to very low RAM which is only 1GB. I went to shop but they said the RAM cannot be upgraded or extended in Android TVs. I tried different video players like Max, VLC but they all produce same malfunction. Is there any solution for playing videos?